# Odoo - Sales Menu Dissapear after Make Small Change

Tags: odoo

I make a really small change on string value in file `addons/product/models/product_template.py`, whose purpose is just to test a text change. I just force the application `Ctrl + C` and start again by `python .\odoo-bin -c .\odoo.conf` to see some changes. But for some reason, the sales menu disappear.

[image]

This image shows the Sales module is already installed
[image]

I can make sure, I have already changed the string value to default value back because I use **Git**

Comment: Have you checked your logged-in user's access rights? In this case he should have rights on "Sales" Access (user's access page). That's one reason it could have changed, but i don't really know why that would change by some python code changes. Alternatively try to find menu item and delete it and then update module `sale_management`. IIRC correct there was a really weird bug in some Odoo versions with disappearing menus.

Comment: This is log in with administrator

Comment: In newer versions the admin account isn't worth that much anymore, on access site i mean. So it is a normal user with some settings accesses.

Answer (score 0):

*Backup first so that if it doesn't work then you can restore.

Try uninstall Sale module and its dependencies and then install them back again.

If it still doesn't work, you can try updating base modules via command.